# React: get raw jsx from children in ParentComponent

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs, react-props

Is it possible to get the actual “raw” `jsx` text wrapped by a `Parent` component (e.g. from `props.children`)?

Given this component:

```
<Parent>
    <Child name={'test'} />
</Parent>
```

**question:**

In `Parent.js`, can I do anything with `this.props.children` (or anything else) to get this (ideally as a string):

**output:**

`"<Child name={'test'} />"`

Comment: Why do you want a string of it? Kind of seems like an XY problem

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800493/3148807) can help

Comment: @Li357 the purpose of this is for a self-documenting page ... doing this makes it easier than having to copy the code. The string is used in combination with Highlight.js to display the source code

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @JoshM. Did you solved this? I'm trying this too. 

Comment: @freesh I'm importing the component itself normally, and then the actual text of the same component file like `import ContentSample from '!!file-loader!./content.tsx';` -- this gives the _path_ to the file. Then you can do a `GET` request for that path, and get the source of the component. So you can then render the actual component as well as display its source.