# How can I pass the original JSX markup to a component for display in the page as code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a self-documenting style guide I'm creating, I have a `CodeSample` component which accepts `children`. I need to render the *exact* string of the `children`, as a string.

```html
<CodeSample language="tsx">
  <div className="some-thing">
    <Icon name="some-icon" />
  </div>
</CodeSample>
```

Within my component I can easily render the children, of course, but I also need to show the raw/original JSX of the children. I have tried `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(...)` but this includes many different attributes and also re-formats the original JSX. I have also tried the `jsx-to-string` package but this also does not give me the exact/original/raw JSX.

**Alternatively** I would be okay with sending a string to the `CodeSample` and using that as the raw sample text, and rendering that string as the actual example component. I have tried to accomplish this using `ReactDomServer.renderToString` and `renderToStaticMarkup` but in both cases the output is *not* the original JSX.

To be clear, the preferred approach is to use HTML as shown above and be able to capture the raw `children` as a string and use that to as the code sample.

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800493/374198) (with some tweaks), but it does not give me the raw/original JSX, it includes additional props and if I aliased an import, it uses the alias's original name.

**Example**

*Original Snippet (JSX)*

```html
<div className="input-group">
  <div className="input-group-prepend">
    <span className="input-group-text">
      <FA icon={faSearch} />
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
</div>
```

*Expected Result (text)*

(Exactly the same as the original.)

*Actual Result*

```html
<div className="input-group">
   <div className="input-group-prepend">
     <span className="input-group-text">
       <FontAwesomeIcon icon={{prefix:fas,iconName:search,icon:[512,512,[],f002,M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z]}} border="false" className="" mask="null" fixedWidth="false" inverse="false" flip="null" listItem="false" pull="null" pulse="false" rotation="null" size="null" spin="false" symbol="false" title="" transform="null" />
     </span>
   </div><input type="text" className="form-control" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Intriguing. I took a crack at updating the title here. It wasn't clear to me what this was about until I read the post. Good luck.

Comment: *but this includes many different attributes and also re-formats the original JSX* - can you elaborate? How exactly it differs?

Comment: Just create task during build to save components as .txt and use right loader for it.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to render the children of `CodeSample` _and_ have the raw JSX snippet available? Having some example output (in HTML) might help folks understand this better

Comment: @estus -- added examples.

Comment: You certainly can't generate original JSX code at runtime because the information is lost at this moment. E.g. `faSearch` variable name. I guess your best bet is to parse source files with Esprima or else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of the input. I realize it was a different kind of question with no straight-forward solution. In the end, here is what I did...

### update the `CodeSample` component

The component fetches the original sample during mount.

#### app/CodeSample.tsx

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Prism } from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { atomDark as style } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism';
import { getSampleTextRequest } from './duck/actions';
import { sampleTextSelector } from './duck/selectors';
import { AppState } from './duck/state';

export class CodeSample extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getSampleText(this.props.samplePath);
  }

  render() {
    const { sampleText } = this.props;

    if (!sampleText) {
      return <em>Loading sample...</em>;
    } else {
      const { children } = this.props;

      if (children) {
        return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col col-xs-12 col-md-6">{this.renderCodeSample()}</div>

            <div className="col col-xs-12 col-md-6 mt-2">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">{children}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return this.renderCodeSample();
      }
    }
  }

  renderCodeSample() {
    const { sampleText } = this.props;
    const language = this.getLanguage();

    return (
      <Prism {...{ language, style }} showLineNumbers={false}>
        {sampleText}
      </Prism>
    );
  }

  getLanguage() {
    const { language, samplePath: path } = this.props;

    return language || /\.(.+?)$/.exec(path)[1];
  }
}

type InjectedProps = {
  sampleText: string;
};

type InjectedActions = {
  getSampleText: typeof getSampleTextRequest;
};

type MyProps = {
  samplePath: string;
  language?: string;
};

type Props = InjectedProps & InjectedActions & MyProps;

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState, props: MyProps) => ({
  sampleText: sampleTextSelector(state, props.samplePath),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getSampleText: getSampleTextRequest,
};

export default connect<InjectedProps, InjectedActions, MyProps, AppState>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CodeSample);
```

### for each code sample, create an actual component

When it's fetched, I pre-process the raw code and ignore any line that doesn't start with spaces. This gives me only the sample within the exported function.

#### addon/addon-button.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon as FA } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default () => (
  <div className="input-group">
    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
    <div className="input-group-append">
      <button className="btn btn-default">
        <FA icon={faSearch} />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

### import and render this component directly in the container, within the `CodeSample`

#### addon/index.ts

For each sample import the component the "normal way" as well as with the `file-loader`, which gives me a relative path to the component's source. I give the `CodeSample` instance the relative path to the original sample, and then render the actual component as its child.

```js
import React from 'react';
import CodeSample from '../../app/CodeSample';
import AddonButton from './addon-button';
import AddonButtonSample from '!!file-loader!./addon-button.tsx';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <a id="addon" />
    <h2>Addons</h2>
    <p>An addon is used to attach an icon, button, etc. to an input.</p>

    ...

    <h3>Buttons</h3>
    <CodeSample samplePath={AddonButtonSample}>
      <AddonButton />
    </CodeSample>
  </div>
);
```

### here is the final result

[image: tada]

Answer (score 0):

There might be libraries to help with this sort of thing. E.g. https://github.com/scniro/react-codemirror2

Comment: That is a code editor, I just need to render a component as well as the raw/original component JSX.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not stored in your Javascript, but it's stored as a set of React.createElement command,.

So one idea is to intercept React.createElement, and grab the values.

Then reverse engerneer a sort of HTML.

Below is an example, it's not complete, but you might be able to enhance it etc.

Of course it's not perfect as some information will be lost eg. `{2+xyz}`, gets transformed to `9`, as that's already been evaluated at compile time.

```js
const ret = [];
const React = {createElement: (...args) => { return args}};

const xyz = 7;

const jsx = <div>
  <div>hello <b>there {2+xyz}</b></div>
  <span>span content {() => "abc"}</span>
</div>;
  

function render(jsx, indent = '') {
  let ret = '';
  ret += `${indent}<${jsx[0]}>`;
  for (let l = 2; l < jsx.length; l += 1) {
    const v = jsx[l];
    if (Array.isArray(v)) ret += '\r\n' + render(v, indent + '  ')
    else if (typeof v === 'function') ret += `{${v}}`;
    else { ret += v;  }
  }
  ret += `${indent}</${jsx[0]}>\r\n`;
  return ret;
}

console.log(render(jsx));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the fact that your JSX is compiled into JavaScript functions you will need to either perform your step at build time, or use a runtime JSX transformer.

For a build time step, you could write your own babel transform and couple that with a custom component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class FA extends Component {
  render () {
    return <div>Hi there {this.props.icon}!</div>
  }
}

// this could be something exported by a preval macro
class CodeSnippet extends Component {
  render () {
    return <>
      {this.props.snippet}
      {this.props.children}
    </>
  }
}

<
  CodeSnippet
attr="1"
>
  <div className="input-group">
  <div className="input-group-prepend">
    <span className="input-group-text">
      <FA icon={faSearch} />
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
</div>
</CodeSnippet>
```

And the transform:

```
export default function (babel) {
  const { types: t } = babel;

  return {
    visitor: {
      JSXIdentifier(path, file) {
        if (path.node.name === "CodeSnippet" && path.container.type === "JSXOpeningElement") {
          const { start, end } = path.parentPath.container

          // we "slice out" the contents of our element, storing them as a string
          const contents = file.file.code.slice(path.parentPath.container.openingElement.end, path.parentPath.container.closingElement.start)
          const contentsEle = t.JSXText(contents)
          // and passing that string to our element as a prop for use later
          path.parentPath.container.openingElement.attributes.push(
            t.JSXAttribute(t.JSXIdentifier("snippet"), t.stringLiteral(contents))
          )
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

which results in:

```
<
CodeSnippet
attr="1" snippet="\n  <div className=\"input-group\">\n  <div className=\"input-group-prepend\">\n    <span className=\"input-group-text\">\n      <FA icon={faSearch} />\n    </span>\n  </div>\n  <input type=\"text\" className=\"form-control\"/>\n</div>\n">

  <div className="input-group">
  <div className="input-group-prepend">
    <span className="input-group-text">
      <FA icon={faSearch} />
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" className="form-control" />
  </div>
</CodeSnippet>;
```

which is rendered out as usual by React:

here's a playable example on [astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/2158485c5f350ea433618f11b7e88767/latest)