# How can I get children source code in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

Is react have a possibility to get children prop source code?

For example I have component with some kind of code...

```js
<SomeComp>
    <Heading>I need this code with Heading tag</Heading>
</SomeComp>
```

How I can get children as a string?

I need something like this...

```js
const SomeComp = ({ children }) => {
    const highlightedCode = highlight(CHILDREN_TO_SOURCE_STRING_FUNCTION(children))
    return (
        <>
            <div>{highlightedCode}</div>
            <div>{children}</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Thx for help

Comment: What's the use case here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: How to get children as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799288/react-how-to-get-children-as-string)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799288/react-how-to-get-children-as-string.  Having said that, you could probably refactor your component tree so this isn't required.  For example, maybe the parent component of `SomeComp` could apply the highlighted code.  If you share more of the code/intention, someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what really you're trying to achieve here but this is what you can do.

```
<SomeComp>
  {`<Heading>I need this code with Heading tag</Heading>`}
</SomeComp>
```